# My NextJS project loads some pages without CSS in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel, css-modules

Recently me and other coworkers have noticed that some of our pages apparently loads without CSS. We are using a mix of module based CSS and Tailwind, it seems the Tailwind styles are loaded properly but not the respective module.css files. We have had issues with this before, and then we had to rewrite the whole site to Tailwind to fix the problem. (The reason for mixing styles is because we are in a transition from module based css to Tailwind, but this wont be complete until at least next year). This error happenes when navigating to pages with the Next.js Link tag, so maybe that is relevant for the problem here.

Here is a screenshot of the page when it loads incorrectly:[As you can see some styles remain, i inspected the different elements and the ones with module.css files have empty style tags, while the tailwind components loads fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZljy.png)

Here is how the page is supposed to look like, and how it loads if i refresh after the style is broken: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PnLL.png)
Is there another way of solving this problem, without rewriting everything to tailwind?

Im trying to remember if this has something to do with settings in the tailwind config file, about purging or content?

I remember reading in a post months ago that you could import the modules into _app.jsx or _document.jsx in the /pages folder in some way, but cannot find the post again. Just let me know if i should add code snippets from somewhere!

I tried purging the cache in the projects Vercel settings, no difference.